# XCode 4 - .xib icon is grayed out

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What does it mean when this icon is greyed out in the file tree viewer?

My main problem is that I am trying to navigate to a view from another view on button click with this method.

```
- (IBAction) organizeMeetingButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    OrganizeMeetingViewController *viewController = [[OrganizeMeetingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrganizeMeetingView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

This is written in controller1 it is trying to access controller 2 (OrganizeMeetingViewController). I believe that the error is in the xcode connections to the actual view. Hence my question about the greyed out icon

Comment: Jonathan, can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: The greyed out icon indicates that there are changes to the file that have not been saved.  It is unlikely the cause of your issues.  More information is necessary.

Comment: That answers my question then about the grayed out. What other information would you like?

Comment: How about a simple `if (x = alloc-init) then push`. The `else` is your today's homework.